# Automatically apply Woocommerce coupon codes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We would like to use Woo-commerce coupons as loyalty card discount, basically customer has loyalty card with number combination like #-##### or ###### (1-12345 or 123456) and when he enters his loyalty card number discount should be added in cart.

Now one option is to import all card numbers to to Woocommerce, but it wouldn't seem rational to have millions coupons there, so is there a way to modify Coupon code field so that whichever number combination customer enters, it automatically adds discount without the need of having the coupon code in system?
In other words we only need that the number combination is following #-##### or ###### structure and we don't even need to link it with customer.

Comment: Do your users have an account on your system/service? If so, flag the user as a loyal user and give them the dicount without entering a code. Otherwise you would have to save the used codes to make sure, that no code is entered twice. And if you do that you are not far away from saving all generated codes (not all possible ones), which makes your question obsolete.

Comment: Users are not connected to system and they do not have and account there. Basically there is absolutely no need to connect coupon/loyalty card number with certain user. To be honest we really don't even care if the loyalty card number even exists, all we need is that the number would be following rule #-##### or ######.